# Tooltip missing value in maps highcharts not working (with R)

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

When creating a map in R with highcharter, I would like to include a tooltip for missing values. To be sure that nullFormat is recognized I included also a datalabel for missing values and this works.

So nullFormat **datalabels is working**.

But nullFormat for a **tooltip is not working**.

```
require(dplyr)

mapdata <- get_data_from_map(download_map_data("custom/usa-and-canada"))

glimpse(mapdata)

data_fake <- mapdata |>
  select(code = `hc-a2`) |>
  mutate(value = 1e5 * abs(rt(nrow(mapdata), df = 10)))

# value NT on not available
data_fake$value[data_fake$code == "AZ"] <- NA

glimpse(data_fake)


highchart(type = "map") |>
  hc_chart(map = download_map_data("custom/usa-and-canada")) |>
  hc_add_series(
    data_fake
    , joinBy = c("hc-a2", "code")
    , name = "Fake data"
    , dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = "{point.name}", nullFormat = "N/A")
  ) |>
  hc_colorAxis(auxpar = NULL) |>
  hc_tooltip(valueDecimals = 0, nullFormat = "Missing data")
```

Comment: This is interesting! It may be a bug, you could add an issue on Github?

Comment: It seems to be an issue related to the wrapper, since in vanilla JS everything works correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ev7nutjf/

Comment: @magdalena, great, thats the solution! Thanks

Comment: @Quinten, yes, I will add this as an issue, together with the solution, because I think nullInteraction should be standard set on TRUE